# Arduino map() method - why?

Tags: serial-port, arduino, mapping, signal-processing, digital

I was just looking at some example code and came across a line, I don't fully understand why it needs to be done. I understand that you are taking in an analog value. This value is between 0 and 1024 apparently? Why is this? Why does the output need to be mapped between 0 and 255? What dictates the arguments that are used here? The line in question :

```
   // map it to the range of the analog out:
      outputValue = map(sensorValue, 0, 1024, 0, 255);
```

Highlighted in the code :

```
created 29 Dec. 2008
 Modified 4 Sep 2010
 by Tom Igoe

 This example code is in the public domain.

 */

// These constants won't change.  They're used to give names
// to the pins used:
const int analogInPin = A0;  // Analog input pin that the potentiometer is attached to
const int analogOutPin = 9; // Analog output pin that the LED is attached to

int sensorValue = 0;        // value read from the pot
int outputValue = 0;        // value output to the PWM (analog out)

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communications at 9600 bps:
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
  // read the analog in value:
  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);            
  **// map it to the range of the analog out:
  outputValue = map(sensorValue, 0, 1024, 0, 255);**  
  // change the analog out value:
  analogWrite(analogOutPin, outputValue);           

  // print the results to the serial monitor:
  Serial.print("sensor = " );                       
  Serial.print(sensorValue);      
  Serial.print("\t output = ");      
  Serial.println(outputValue);   

  // wait 10 milliseconds before the next loop
  // for the analog-to-digital converter to settle
  // after the last reading:
  delay(10);                     
}
```

Thanks very much for the replies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The analog output only has an acceptable range between 0 and 255.

Therefore, the value has to be mapped within the acceptable range.

Documentation for map method is here: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/map

> Because the Arduino has an analogRead resolution of 0-1023, and an analogWrite resolution of only 0-255, this raw data from the potentiometer needs to be scaled before using it...

This explanation comes from an Arduino sensor tutorial(under the 'Code' header):  http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogInOutSerial

Comment: One could argue, that integer division by 4 would do the work too, but map() works fine as well.

Comment: Why is analogInput allowed to be 0-1024 if output must be between 0-255?

Comment: @SimonKiely I am not certain of the technical limitation or the design decisions leading to those limitations.  If I were to guess, it has to do with the fact that the microcontroller has limitations for a variety of reasons such as size, memory, etc, and the designers decided that a higher input resolution would be more useful than a high output resolution.

Comment: @SimonKiely This link explains the input resolution: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogInputPins  I am sure that the output has a similar limitation.

Comment: Thanks very much, very interesting and informative responses ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Why? Sometimes you will need to translate 0 to 1023 into a range of values OTHER THAN 0 to 1023 and the `map()` function is an attempt to make this easier for you, the engineer. [I explain one situation in some detail on this forum post](https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=36254), where I am able to convert the 0 to 90 or 100 indexes of an array having values of 0 to 1023 integers into an x-y graphical plot!

`idx` ranges from 0 to some value near 100.
`test[idx]` is the ADC values, so range from 0 to 1023.

```
int x1= map(1, 0, idxmax, 0, 160);
int y1= yf - 2 - map(test[1], TPS_floor[_tps], TPS_max[_tps], 0, dy);
for(idx=0; idx < idxmax-1;  ){
    int x0 = map(idx, 0, idxmax, 0, 160);
    int y0 = yf - 2 - map(test[idx], TPS_floor[_tps], TPS_max[_tps], 0, dy);
    tft.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1, YELLOW);
    idx++;
    x1 = map(idx+1, 0, idxmax, 0, 160);
    y1 = yf - 2 - map(test[idx+1], TPS_floor[_tps], TPS_max[_tps], 0, dy);
}
```

So the above code translates an x of 0-~100 and y of 0-1023 into this:
[image: map() translated an array's index and its values into that plot!]

My build's [write up is here](https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=36254). (and as of 7-31-2013, is in progress)

I, personally, find that a clear illustration of "why" is the best explanation. I hope that my answer helps anyone questioning this "why" as to ... why.

Comment: Very interesting and informative. Still working my way through the forum post but I'm finding this very absorbing!

Comment: Thanks, Simon! Think of `map()` as some kind of scaling function...? You're welcome to ask questions, etc, on that forum. :)